# Can I use a <tr> tag inside a <tr> in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, html-table, vuejs2

I have the code below that creates a dynamic table in vue.js.

```
<template>
    <tr class="left-align"  v-for="(item,index) in itemList" :key="index.id">
        <td>{{item.items}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="left-align"  v-for="(item,index) in itemList" :key="index.id">
        <td>{{item.items}}(future)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="left-align"  v-for="(item,index) in itemList" :key="index.id">
        <td>GAP</td>
    </tr>
</template>
```

But the output for this one is not what I'm expecting. The result is like this:

[image]

How can I reach my expected output? Because if I try to wrap them in one `<tr>` tag like:

```
<tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tr>
```

It says:

> Parsing error: x-invalid-end-tag

Comment: Where is your closing </TD> ?

Comment: @HugoCox — End tags for td elements are optional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap you `tr`s with `tbody`(or just with `template` tag) and use only one `v-for`:

```
 <tbody v-for="(item,index) in itemList" :key="index">
    <tr class="left-align">
        <td>{{item.items}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="left-align">
        <td>{{item.items}}(future)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="left-align">
        <td>GAP</td>
    </tr>
 </tbody>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, more simplified and cleaner work :) But my problem now, my headers are gone. Haha!

Comment: Using `<tbody>` directly under a `<tr>` is not valid in HTML.

Comment: I see it now. This seems not feasible coz it adds new table in one row (one row displays all data and others have none) and my headers are extended far right.

Comment: @ramedju I suggest removing the parent `tr` if there is one and add `tbody` in `table`. See https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/159309/

Answer (score 0):

In HTML, it is not allowed to write a `tr` in a `tr` as far as I know. You should be able to achieve what you want with a table though.

```
<template>
  <td>
    <table>

<tr class="left-align"  v-for="(item,index) in itemList" :key="index.id">
    <td>{{item.items}}</td>
</tr>
<tr class="left-align"  v-for="(item,index) in itemList" :key="index.id">
    <td>{{item.items}}(future)</td>
</tr>
<tr class="left-align"  v-for="(item,index) in itemList" :key="index.id">
    <td>GAP</td>
</tr>

    </table>
  </td>
</template>
```

expected output should be:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <table>

<tr>
    <td>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>
    </td>
</tr>

    </table>
  </td>
</tr>
```

A good old way to handle this kind of error is to use a [HTML Validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea). Your HTML should not throw any errors nor warning. Try copy/paste this for example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>sd</title>
</head>
<body>

<table>
<tr>
<td>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            foo
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            bar
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You mean I should use `<tr>` tag instead of `<template>` tag?

Comment: @ramedju I mean that you should not use a `<tr>` directly under another `<tr>`. I will edit to add more clarity.

Comment: As per your edit, the output is still the same as before.

Comment: I can't see your image. I am not sure what you want. You said that you got an error and my answer explains why :)

Comment: Yes this solves the error but the output is still the same .. You can see it [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krUzg.png)